# Apollo client overwrites existing object in cache with incoming object from server

Tags: apollo-client

I'm using apollo client's (cache.modify) api to update `MyObject` in the cache on each mutation, so that in case of failed write to server the updated object is available in the cache. `MyObject` is normalized with user defined id.

When fetching a list of `MyObject` through a query, I noticed that the object with the same id in both incoming and existing list is identical and that the object that was originally in the cache is overwritten with the value in the server. I added a merge function to `MyObject` for debugging and found that the object gets overwritten there. I'm using `cache-and-network` cache policy and have checked that cache.modify indeed updates the object in the cache.

```
  //MyObject schema
  MyObject {
    my_obj_id : number,
    my_obj_field : string,
    version : number
  }

  typePolicies: {
    MyObject: {
      keyFields: ["my_object_id"],
      //merge: false, ->  this doesn't work

      fields: {
        my_obj_field: {
          merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
           // Here existing and incoming get merged, but I'd like to merge based on version which is not available here.
          }
      } 
     } // MyObject

   Query: {
      fields: {
        MyObject: {

          merge(existing = [], incoming = [], { cache, args, readField }) {
            // Obj with the same my_obj_id say(99) in both incoming and existing is a ref and hence identical.
            const incomingObj = incoming[0];  // lets assume we are only interested in the first value.
            const found = existing.find(
                (e) =>
                  readField("my_obj_id", e) === readField("my_obj_id", incomingObj) &&
                  readField("version", e) > readField("version", incomingObj)
              );
          // found is always undefined, not because the value doesn't exist in existing, but because it is identical to the one in incoming list.
 
          }
        }
     } // Query

   }
```

I have so far tried the following

1. Disabled merge by setting `merge:false` in `MyObject`  - but this has no effect.
2. Defined merge function in `MyObject`, but the logic depends on another field (`version`) which is not available in `my_obj_field` so this doesn't work either. Over here I noticed that both existing and incoming are indeed different and quite certain that the incoming object replaces the existing object here.

I'm now considering querying the cache available in merge function arguments of `MyObject` to decide whether to keep the incoming object or existing object, but this doesn't feel like the right way forward. Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this happens due to incorrect cache writing. For example, query variables are not the same as in cache or objects have different fields and you didn't provide custom IDs for the entities, or types of data differ, so Apollo doesn't know which is incorrect and Apollo's solution is simply refetch.

In my opinion, typePolicies instructions in docs are not clear enough and unobvious. You can write cache using as you mentioned cache.modify which is suitable only for object entities you can reference by field. If you want for example change the list (add or remove items, or merge with others) you should use cache.readQuery and cache.writeQuery.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/

This is how you do it:

1. Get existing cache with cache.readQuery

```
const cachedList = cache.readQuery<TypesForYourListQuery>({
            variables,
            query: GraphqlListQueryDocument,
        });
```

2. You wrtie to cache with cache.writeQuery

```
cache.writeQuery<TypesForYourListQuery>({
                    variables,
                    query: GraphqlListQueryDocument,
                    data: {
                        list: {
                            __typename: 'SomeListEntity',
                            count: data.count,
                            items: [...cachedList.items, ...data.items]
                        },
                    },
                });
```

Make sure the variables of read and write query are the same, if they are not you simply won't update the existing query cache but create a new unused one.