# How to disable merge for normalized objects in Apollo Client cache?

Tags: apollo-client

I'm running into a situation with `Apollo Client` cache where a normalized object gets automatically merged causing the already updated object in the cache to be overwritten with value from server. I noticed this when merging array of objects in the query merge function. The desired object in the cache was already overwritten so the incoming and existing array contained identical objects (ref actually).

Already tried setting merge to false which made no difference.

Comment: Posting this shorter version of a more detailed post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76029456/apollo-client-overwrites-existing-object-in-cache-with-incoming-object-from-serv for easier read.